# record audio from embedded video

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, web-audio-api

I like to use the audio context analyzer to take-in the combined audio output of a web page and process it. I have an embedded youtube video and an audio track running at the same time and like to use the analytical capabilities to visualize the combined audio.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, no.  It's not yet possible.  It will be, in some contexts at least, but it doesn't work today.